# Using a DB2 driver to access as400

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange, classnotfoundexception

I'm relatively new to SQL, I am having some problems connecting to an AS/400 DB2 database.

I've managed to connect to MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server and Netezza databases without much trouble, but I cannot connect to this DB!

I keep getting the following error:

> Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I've tried `jt400` and `db2jcc` drivers, and tried the class.forName's of `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` and `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver`, but no combination of the two have helped.

Example is:

```
public Connection startMyRexConnection() {
        Connection connect = null;
        ConfigReader.main();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(ConfigReader.getREXurl(), ConfigReader.getREXuser(), ConfigReader.getREXpassword());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to load DB2 driver");
            System.err.println(e);
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.err.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("Driver loaded, but cannot connect to db: " + ConfigReader.getREXurl());
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Check classpath. Cannot load db driver: " + "com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");
        }
        rexCon = connect;
        return connect;
    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Edit:
This is the output from e.printStackTrace(); :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.vat.ui.RexConnection.startMyRexConnection(RexConnection.java:26)
    at org.apache.jsp.loginRequestHandler_jsp._jspService(loginRequestHandler_jsp.java:143)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
```

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` when displaying exceptions, and include the full stacktrace.

Comment: Now added in edit section.

Comment: Well you don't have the driver in the classpath, or you misspelled the driver class name.

Comment: Thank you, I had set the build path on the app in Eclipse to look at my local copy of the jar, whereas I should have pointed it at the tomcat copy.
Now I just need to get the connection string correct! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct driver for IBM i is the jt400 driver, and the connection string is simple:

```
jdbc:as400://<host>;
```

You have the correct class name:

```
com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just sat with my mentor and tried some stuff, indeed you are correct, my mistake was including the port number in the connection string (which I hadn't included in my post). Rookie mistake.